# LINQ Group By into a Dictionary Object

Tags: linq, dictionary

I am trying to use LINQ to create a `Dictionary<string, List<CustomObject>>` from a `List<CustomObject>`. I can get this to work using "var", but I don't want to use anonymous types. Here is what I have

```
var x = (from CustomObject o in ListOfCustomObjects
      group o by o.PropertyName into t
      select t.ToList());
```

I have also tried using `Cast<>()` from the LINQ library once I have `x`, but I get compile problems to the effect of it being an invalid cast.

Comment: What if you try var x = (from CustomObject o in ListOfCustomObjects group o by o.PropertyName into t select t).ToList();

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to do this rather than using ToLookup, which is designed for this?

Comment: Jon, could you please post an example of how ToLookup works in this situation? I am not familiar with that LINQ method.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're awesome! (I mean, everyone knew that already, but still.) Reason I wasn't planning on using ToLookup was cause I'd never heard of it until now. Now I know!

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, using `var` isn't using an "anonymous" type, it's using an "implicit" type. Anonymous types are new classes created by the compiler to handle the construction `new { thing = "stuff" };`. Implicit types are existing classes, `var` is just a convenient way to reference them when the variable is being assigned immediately, the variable type can be inferred from the type of the object being assigned to it. You can even implicitly type a variable referencing an anonymous type, i.e.: `var a = new { thing = "stuff" };`

Answer (score 543, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, List<CustomObject>> myDictionary = ListOfCustomObjects
    .GroupBy(o => o.PropertyName)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: Unless you're needing a property from 'CustomObject' as the list value (not shown in this answer) it's worth checking his codeliness Jon Skeet's comment to the question recommending ToLookup().

Comment: this is the way to do it if a non immutable result is desired. ToLookup is immutable.

Comment: My 2 Cents (just 'cause it kept me struggling for an hour :) ): when grouping by a property, make sure the Property HAS a value! Otherwise the Todict-method fails generating key (for String-Properties at least...) :)

Comment: `.GroupBy(o => o.PropertyName).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList())` This could be a part of extension Linq library. so we only has to do `.ToDictionary(o=>o.PropertyName)`

Comment: @Jaider, there already is such functionality: just replace `ToDictionary` with `ToLookup`.

Answer (score 39):

I cannot comment on @Michael Blackburn, but I guess you got the downvote because the GroupBy is not necessary in this case.

Use it like:

```
var lookupOfCustomObjects = listOfCustomObjects.ToLookup(o=>o.PropertyName);
var listWithAllCustomObjectsWithPropertyName = lookupOfCustomObjects[propertyName]
```

Additionally, I've seen this perform way better than when using GroupBy().ToDictionary().

Comment: I was performing a transliteration, not responding to the question in the best possible manner.

Answer (score 3):

For @atari2600, this is what the answer would look like using ToLookup in lambda syntax:

```
var x = listOfCustomObjects
    .GroupBy(o => o.PropertyName)
    .ToLookup(customObject => customObject);
```

Basically, it takes the IGrouping and materializes it for you into a dictionary of lists, with the values of PropertyName as the key.

Comment: Why a downvote? Is this not accurate/answering the question?

Comment: In case you missed it, @RuudvK mentioned in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39974970/945456) that he suspects the downvote is because the GroupBy is unnecessary. `ToLookup` has an overload that'll get the job done.

Comment: I did miss that response, thanks for tagging me. Makes sense, the Grouping is syntactically unnecessary, i was only leaving it in to make the transition from query syntax to method syntax clearer .

Comment: GroupBy (the overload with just one parameter) returns a IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>
the subsequent ToLookup then turns it into a quite complicated type that is not even similar to a IDictionary<TKey,IList<TSource>>

just the ToLookup returns the proper type.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you if you to Get a Count of words. if you want a key and a list of items just modify the code to have the **value** be **group.ToList()**

```
    var s1 = "the best italian resturant enjoy the best pasta";    
    var D1Count = s1.ToLower().Split(' ').GroupBy(e => e).Select(group => new { key = group.Key, value = group.Count() }).ToDictionary(e => e.key, z => z.value);


//show the results
                    Console.WriteLine(D1Count["the"]);
                    foreach (var item in D1Count)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Key +" "+ item.Value);
                    }
```

Comment: Answer is a bit out of context since it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count). But still, if you modify your code to use `group.ToList()` instead of counting, it would be the same solution as the accepted answer: `GroupBy` and then `ToDictionary`, without creating the anonymous object.

Answer (score -3):

The following worked for me.

```
var temp = ctx.Set<DbTable>()
  .GroupBy(g => new { g.id })
  .ToDictionary(d => d.Key.id);
```