# LINQ with groupby and count

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

This is pretty simple but I'm at a loss:
Given this type of data set:

```
UserInfo(name, metric, day, other_metric)
```

and this sample data set:

```
joe  1 01/01/2011 5
jane 0 01/02/2011 9
john 2 01/03/2011 0
jim  3 01/04/2011 1
jean 1 01/05/2011 3
jill 2 01/06/2011 5
jeb  0 01/07/2011 3
jenn 0 01/08/2011 7
```

I'd like to retrieve a table that lists metrics in order(0,1,2,3..) with the total number of times the count occurs. So from this set, you'd end up with:

```
0 3    
1 2    
2 2    
3 1
```

I'm grappling with the LINQ syntax but am stuck on where to put a groupby and count...
any help?

POST Edit: I was never able to get the posted answers to work as they always returned one record with the number of different counts. However, I was able to put together a LINQ to SQL example that did work:

```
var pl = from r in info
         orderby r.metric    
         group r by r.metric into grp
         select new { key = grp.Key, cnt = grp.Count()};
```

This result gave me an ordered set of records with 'metrics' and the number of users associated with each. I'm clearly new to LINQ in general and to my untrained eye this approach seems very similar to the pure LINQ approach yet gave me a different answer.

Comment: Yes I have, but jimmy's explanation helped me more so. However I was never able to get his example to work but it did lead me in a new direction.

Comment: @Jimmy used the functional syntax for LINQ expressions rather than standard LINQ query syntax, plus he decided to show the immediate execution of those functions rather than the delayed execution format. For a new person that would be confusing. Don't know why he did that.

Comment: If you need to include subtype within group, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625965/linq-groupby-with-count

Answer (score 532, accepted):

After calling `GroupBy`, you get a series of groups `IEnumerable<Grouping>`, where each Grouping itself exposes the `Key` used to create the group and also is an `IEnumerable<T>` of whatever items are in your original data set. You just have to call `Count()` on that Grouping to get the subtotal.

```
foreach(var line in data.GroupBy(info => info.metric)
                        .Select(group => new { 
                             Metric = group.Key, 
                             Count = group.Count() 
                        })
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Metric))
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", line.Metric, line.Count);
}
```

---

> This was a brilliantly quick reply but I'm having a bit of an issue with the first line, specifically "data.groupby(info=>info.metric)"

I'm assuming you already have a list/array of some `class` that looks like

```
class UserInfo {
    string name;
    int metric;
    ..etc..
} 
...
List<UserInfo> data = ..... ;
```

When you do `data.GroupBy(x => x.metric)`, it means "for each element `x` in the IEnumerable defined by `data`, calculate it's `.metric`, then group all the elements with the same metric into a `Grouping` and return an `IEnumerable` of all the resulting groups. Given your example data set of

```
    <DATA>           | Grouping Key (x=>x.metric) |
joe  1 01/01/2011 5  | 1
jane 0 01/02/2011 9  | 0
john 2 01/03/2011 0  | 2
jim  3 01/04/2011 1  | 3
jean 1 01/05/2011 3  | 1
jill 2 01/06/2011 5  | 2
jeb  0 01/07/2011 3  | 0
jenn 0 01/08/2011 7  | 0
```

it would result in the following result after the groupby:

```
(Group 1): [joe  1 01/01/2011 5, jean 1 01/05/2011 3]
(Group 0): [jane 0 01/02/2011 9, jeb  0 01/07/2011 3, jenn 0 01/08/2011 7]
(Group 2): [john 2 01/03/2011 0, jill 2 01/06/2011 5]
(Group 3): [jim  3 01/04/2011 1]
```

Comment: This was a brilliantly quick reply but I'm having a bit of an issue with the first line, specifically "data.groupby(info=>info.metric)". Plainly 'data' is the currently data set but what does 'info.metric' represet? the class definition?

Comment: "info.metric" would be the metric property/field on the UserInfo class you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks figured that out but actually this appears to give me a single value - namely the total number of different metric counts.  In this example I get "metrics  4" which indicates to me how many different counts I have.

Comment: Wow. You totally explained grouping!! That alone was worth the post.... i stil get the "metrics 4" result but thanks!

Comment: Finally got it to work. Outstanding time to answer sub 1 minute.

Comment: The start of this answer, "after calling GroupBy, you get a series of groups IEnumerable<Grouping>, where each Grouping itself exposes the Key used to create the group and also is an IEnumerable<T> of whatever items are in your original data set", is the clearest explanation of LINQ GroupBy I've yet read, thank you.

Answer (score 88):

Assuming `userInfoList` is a `List<UserInfo>`:

```
var groups = userInfoList.GroupBy(n => n.metric)
                         .Select(n => new
                          {
                               MetricName = n.Key,
                               MetricCount = n.Count()
                          })
                         .OrderBy(n => n.MetricName);
```

The lambda function for `GroupBy()`, `n => n.metric` means that it will get field `metric` from every `UserInfo` object encountered. The type of `n` is depending on the context, in the first occurrence its of type `UserInfo`, because the list contains `UserInfo` objects. In the second occurrence `n` is of type `Grouping`, because now its a list of `Grouping` objects.

`Grouping`s have extension methods like `.Count()`, `.Key()` and pretty much anything else you would expect. Just as you would check `.Length` on a `string`, you can check `.Count()` on a group.

Answer (score 28):

```
userInfos.GroupBy(userInfo => userInfo.metric)
        .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
        .Select(group => Tuple.Create(group.Key, group.Count()));
```