# Counting Using Group By Linq

Tags: c#, linq, count, group-by, distinct

I have an object that looks like this:

```
Notice 
{
    string Name,
    string Address 
}
```

In a `List<Notice>` I want to output All distinct Name and how many times the particular appears in the collection.

For example:

```
Notice1.Name="Travel"
Notice2.Name="Travel"
Notice3.Name="PTO"
Notice4.Name="Direct"
```

I want the output

```
Travel - 2
PTO - 1
Direct -1
```

I can get the distinct names fine with this code but I can't seem to get the counts all in 1 linq statement

```
  theNoticeNames= theData.Notices.Select(c => c.ApplicationName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ with groupby and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
var noticesGrouped = notices.GroupBy(n => n.Name).
                     Select(group =>
                         new
                         {
                             NoticeName = group.Key,
                             Notices = group.ToList(),
                             Count = group.Count()
                         });
```

Answer (score 50):

A variation on Leniel's answer, using a [different overload of `GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx):

```
var query = notices.GroupBy(n => n.Name, 
                (key, values) => new { Notice = key, Count = values.Count() });
```

Basically it just elides the `Select` call.