# List Categories and it's count of products with LinQ using Lambda or classic expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to list the categories and the count of the products that belong to each category using LinQ lambda or classic expressions.

This is the Class:

```
  class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the list I am using just to figure out how  the list looks like.

```
  IEnumerable<Product> productList = new List<Product>  {
          new Product  { ProductID = 1, ProductName = "Chai", Category = "Beverages",
            UnitPrice = 18.0000M, UnitsInStock = 39 },
          new Product{ ProductID = 2, ProductName = "Chang", Category = "Beverages",
            UnitPrice = 19.0000M, UnitsInStock = 17 },
          new Product{ ProductID = 3, ProductName = "Aniseed Syrup", Category = "Condiments",
            UnitPrice = 10.0000M, UnitsInStock = 13 },
          new Product{ ProductID = 4, ProductName = "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning", Category = "Condiments",......and so on..
```

I have a method that returns a list called listProd. 
For instance, I am able to  get the count of products in "Beverages" category individually, but this way I have to create as many queries as Categories are...(not good)..

```
int query = listProd.Where(p => p.Category == "Beverages").Count();
```

So what I want is to create query something like this:

Category, count(products that belongs to the Category)

Beverages, 5

Condiments, 7

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270018/counting-using-group-by-linq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ with groupby and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this LINQ query

```
 var result = productList.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                         .Select(y => new { Category = y.Key, Count = y.Count() });
```

First group by the category and then use `Key` and `Count()` to get the result objects.

With the sample data you've provided the result will look like

[image]

If you want to get more information and samples about LINQ I recommend [101 LINQ Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/dotnet/try-samples/101-linq-samples/).

**edit**

Accoring to your comment:

You could use the `Where` statement to get only categorie which have more than 4 products.

```
var result = productList.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                        .Where(x => x.Count() > 4)
                        .Select(y => new { Category = y.Key, Count = y.Count() });= y.Count() });
```

Comment: what about a restriction listing only those categories with more than 4 products? I trying to figure out throug 101 LINQ SAMPLES. I am a newbie and  seems like I have a long way to walk

Answer (score 3):

Use the following peace code

```
  IEnumerable<Product> productList = new List<Product>  {
      new Product  { ProductID = 1, ProductName = "Chai", Category = "Beverages",
        UnitPrice = 18.0000M, UnitsInStock = 39 },
      new Product{ ProductID = 2, ProductName = "Chang", Category = "Beverages",
        UnitPrice = 19.0000M, UnitsInStock = 17 },
      new Product{ ProductID = 3, ProductName = "Aniseed Syrup", Category = "Condiments",
        UnitPrice = 10.0000M, UnitsInStock = 13 },
      new Product{ ProductID = 4, ProductName = "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning", Category = "Condiments"}


    };
        var list = (from x in productList
                    group x.Category by x.Category into g
                    select new { Category = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```