# Linq Group and Count in IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following LINQ Query in my controller which queries my IEnumerable Collection, the grouping works when I output the results in my view but when I try and add a count on the column I have grouped it fails miserably.  I was wondering if anyone could help at all, I have been looking at previous examples but I am missing something obvious.

Grouped //Working fine and returning grouped Descriptions

```
itemdetails = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
                           join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
                           where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
                           join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
                           where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
                           select i).GroupBy(it => it.DESC).Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x => x.DESC)
```

What I have tried to get Group and Count in LINQ  //Not working returning error

```
itemdetails = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
                           join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
                           where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
                           join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
                           where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
                           select i).GroupBy(it => it.DESC).Select(grp => new {DESC = grp.key, Count = grp.COUNT()}).OrderBy(x => x.DESC)
```

This give me the following error :-
cannot implicitly convert type system linq iorderedqueryable to system.collections.generic.ienumerable

Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count

Comment: What is the type of `itemdetails`? This problem probably comes from the fact that it's not compatible with an `IEnumerable` of your anonymous class.

Comment: Hi Alxandr, itemdetails is an ienumerable collection in a viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two queries are returning different data, the first is returning items of type `ItemDetail`, while the second query is returning items of an anonymous type.

If you want an IEnumerable of an anonymous type, you will need to declare it using the `var` keyword, i.e.

```
var itemdetails = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
                           join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
                           where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
                           join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
                           where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
                           select i).GroupBy(it => it.DESC).Select(grp => new {DESC = grp.key, Count = grp.COUNT()}).OrderBy(x => x.DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks Lukazoid, so why does it allow me to group on the column DESC in the first query but when I try and Count on the same column in db.ITEMDETAILS it returns the error?  I presume because it does not know what count is in my ienumerable collection itemdetails?

Comment: This would be down to the ORM you are using, it seems like it is not able to translate the expression for `.Count()` into a SQL query.