# How to frame linq query with COUNT, GROUP BY and select statement?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have to form a linq query with select, count and select statement

My table looks like this

```
Date          Name 
2015-04-25    xxy
2015-04-25    pap
2015-04-25    sms
2014-07-12    bljoe
2014-07-12    olk
```

I want the result similar to this

```
Date          Count
2015-04-25      3
2014-07-12      2
```

My sql query will be like this :

```
select t.date, COUNT(k.Name)
from table t
group by t.date
```

But I dont know how my linq query should be :

I tried like this. But it returned exception

```
var result = (from ka in _db.table
                          group t by new {t.Date} into g

                          select new 
                          {
                              Date = g.Key,
                              Count = g.FirstOrDefault().Name.Count()
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: 'Count = g.Count()', or am I missing something?

Comment: Ya. It worked. Thanks vc :)

Comment: I believe this has been asked and answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count