# Linq .GroupBy() with count of subtypes and Total Group Count

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table that I need to summarize in a report.  This is my sample table.

```
                Orders
_____________________________________
CustomerId | CustomerName | OrderType 
___________|______________|__________ 
1          |     Adam     | Shoe
1          |     Adam     | Shoe
1          |     Adam     | Shoe
1          |     Adam     | Hat
1          |     Adam     | Hat
2          |     Bill     | Shoe
2          |     Bill     | Hat
3          |     Carl     | Sock
3          |     Carl     | Hat
```

I am trying to summarize this to pass back in my viewmodel without a loop.  This is the result that I am attempting to achieve.

```
CustomerName | Shoe | Hat | Sock | Total Orders
------------ | ---- | --- | ---- | ------------
Adam         |   3  |  2  |  0   |      5
Bill         |   1  |  1  |  0   |      2
Carl         |   0  |  1  |  1   |      2

//var resultList = dbContext.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.CustomerId);
```

How can I use GroupBy and Count to achieve my desired results?  Would that be the best approach to take?

Comment: include the current query that you are using

Comment: agree to @un-lucky.. and what db you are working

Comment: Please clarify if list of items is fixed to just those 3 or you want number of columns to vary based on different items

Comment: All answers have assumed that the number of `OrderType` is limited to the values provided in the example, but the OP has not confirmed/infirmed this yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[group clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)

```
var summary = from order in dbContext.Orders
              group order by order.CustomerId into g
              select new { 
                  CustomerName = g.First().CustomerName , 
                  Shoe = g.Count(s => s.OrderType == "Shoe"),
                  Hat = g.Count(s => s.OrderType == "Hat"),
                  Sock = g.Count(s => s.OrderType == "Sock"),
                  TotalOrders = g.Count()
              };
```

Comment: nice solution.  I changed .First() to .FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 8):

if items are fixed:

```
public List<OrderViewModel> GetCustOrders()
{
    var query = orders
        .GroupBy(c => c.CustomerName)
        .Select(o => new OrderViewModel{
            CustomerName = o.Key,
            Shoe = o.Where(c => c.OrderType == "Shoe").Count(c => c.CustomerId),
            Hat = o.Where(c => c.OrderType == "Hat").Count(c => c.CustomerId),
            Sock = o.Where(c => c.OrderType == "Sock").Count(c => c.CustomerId),
            Total = o.Count(c => c.CustomerId)
        });

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

use SQL is one option, i tested it and get exactly what you want:

```
select p.*, t.total as 'Total Orders' from 
(
    select CustomerName, count(CustomerId) total from Orders group by CustomerName
) as t inner join
(
    select * from Orders
    pivot(count(CustomerId) 
        for OrderType in ([Shoe], [Hat], [Sock])
        ) as piv
)as p on p.CustomerName = t.CustomerName
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.