# Simple LINQ query to count by month

Tags: c#, linq

This should be a fairly basic LINQ query but I am confused on how to get this in the format I need.

Here's what I have right now, which I realize isn't even close:

```
        var accidents = DataParser
            .Parser
            .ParseData()
            .Where(w => w.EventDate.Year == year)
            .GroupBy(g => g.EventDate.Month)
            .Count()
            .ToList();
```

The `ToList` isn't going to work here due to the `Count`.

I need the data in the simple format of:

> Month Number | EventCount
>
> 1 | 45
>
> 2 | 62
>
> 3 | 42

... etc through month 12, preferably as a `List<Events>` (the `DataParser` returns `Events` objects).

Comment: you need `.Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }` instead of `Count()`

Comment: How can a `List<Events>` represent the result you want? Wouldn't a `Dictionary<int, int>` be better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ with groupby and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count) This question [Linq .GroupBy() with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625965/linq-groupby-with-count) is almost the same too

Comment: @trailmax That did it, post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your group like this:

```
    var accidents = DataParser
        .Parser
        .ParseData()
        .Where(w => w.EventDate.Year == year)
        .GroupBy(g => g.EventDate.Month)
        .Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
        .ToList();
```

That will give a list of anonymous objects. If you need list of `Event`s, create `Event` object instead: `.Select(g => new Event() { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }`