# How to group by multiple fields and get the count of another field

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq

So let's say I have a simple class like

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and I have an `IQueryable<Person>` called `persons`. What I'm trying to do is the equivalent of

```
SELECT
   FirstName, 
   LastName,
   COUNT(Age) As AgeCount
FROM dbo.Persons
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

if we were in SQL land. How do I write this in LINQ?

I've looked at posts like [linq with groupby and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count) and none of them are exactly like my scenario.

Comment: I think you misinterpret the SQL `COUNT` function. If `Age` is non nullable field, `COUNT(Age)` is the same as `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)`. If you had in mind `COUNT(DISTINCT Age)`, that's a totally different story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can group by an anonymous object, then project each group to select the desired properties:

```
var result = persons
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName })
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
        LastName = g.Key.LastName,
        AgeCount = g.Count()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's should be somethilg like this:

```
persons.GroupBy(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName })
.Select(p => new { 
p.Key.FirstName, 
p.Key.LastName, 
AgeCount = p.Where(p1 => p1.Age != null).Select(p1 => p1.Age).Count() });
```