# Nested Queries in Linq

Tags: linq

I have my table structure like this.

ContinentTable => CountryTable => UserTable

User has CountryId. Country has ContinentId.

I want to query all the continents with the number of users in each.

I achieved this via SQL. But I want to use linq extension method since Im working with EF Core.

Here is my sql query

```
SELECT Continent.Id, Continent.Name, COUNT(Usr.UserName) AS 'User Count'
FROM Continents Continent, Countries Country, Users Usr 
WHERE Continent.Id = Country.ContinentId
AND Country.Id = Usr.CountryId
GROUP BY Continent.Id, Continent.Name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ with groupby and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your object model:

```
Dim continents As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)))

    continents = New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))) From
        {
            {"Europe", New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) From
                {
                    {"France", New List(Of String) From {"Antoine", "Serge"}},
                    {"Germany", New List(Of String) From {"Hans", "Wolfgang"}},
                    {"Spain", New List(Of String) From {"Pablo", "Pedro"}}
                }
            },
            {"America", New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) From
                {
                    {"USA", New List(Of String) From {"Kevin", "Caleb"}},
                    {"Mexico", New List(Of String) From {"Gustavo", "Oscar"}},
                    {"Brazil", New List(Of String) From {"Alexandro"}}
                }
            }
        }
```

Then this would be your LINQ query:

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = continents.Select(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))(Function(x As KeyValuePair(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)))) New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(x.Key, x.Value.Select(Of Integer)(Function(y As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String))) y.Value.Count).Sum))
```