# How to write a count and group by month query with linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

This is my first C# application in ASP.NET Core using Entity Framework Core and I'm trying to write the following MySQL query in Linq:

```
SELECT districtid, COUNT(id), MONTH(registerDate)
FROM StreetCrimes
GROUP BY districtid, MONTH(registerDate)
```

The problem I'm facing is writing the linq code. I've tried the following to get close to the answer:

```
var StreetCrimes = this.database.StreetCrimes
        .Select(s => s.district)
        .Count(s => s.id > 0)
        .GroupBy(s => s.district)
        .ThenBy(s => s.registerDate);
```

Any help making this possible would be appreciated.

My `StreetCrime` class:

```
public class StreetCrime
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string caseNumber { get; set; }
    public District district { get; set; }
    public DateTime registerDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan crimeTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what are u trying to do exactly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ with groupby and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count)

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm trying to count the amount of crimes commited in each month grouped by district id

Comment: @Debreker,take a look at my solution , i've given you three options,you can go with any :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @jdweng I got closer to my answer. However I Needed the total amount each month.

```
        var StreetCrimes = this.database.StreetCrimes
        .Where(x => x.id > 0)
        .GroupBy(s => new {district = s.district, date = s.registerDate.Month})
        .Select(x => new { count = x.Count(), district = x.Key.district, date = x.Key.date})
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

District needs to inherit IEqualityComparer for the GroupBy to work.  The linq should look like this :

```
       var StreetCrimes = this.database.StreetCrimes
       .Where(x => x.id > 0)
       .GroupBy(s => new {district = s.district, date = s.registerDate})
       .Select(x => new { count = x.Count(), district = x.Key.district, date = x.Key.date})
       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with LINQ

```
  var StreetCrimes = this.database.StreetCrimes
   .Where(x => x.id > 0)
   .GroupBy(s => new {district = s.district, date = s.registerDate})
   .Select(x => new { count = x.Count(), district = x.Key.district, date = x.Key.date})
   .ToList();
```

but you can also go with a `DataTable`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT districtid,COUNT(id),MONTH(registerDate) FROM StreetCrimes GROUP BY districtid,MONTH(registerDate)",connectionString)

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ada.Fill(dt)
int crimeCount = dt.Rows.Count();
```

or maybe two lines will do :

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT districtid,     COUNT(id),MONTH(registerDate) FROM StreetCrimes GROUP BY districtid,MONTH(registerDate)",connectionString)

 int crimeCount = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var StreetCrimes = this.database.StreetCrimes
       .Where(x => x.id > 0)
       .GroupBy(s => new {district = s.district, month = s.registerDate.Month})
       .Select(x => new { count = x.Count(), district = x.Key.district, month = x.Key.month})
       .ToList();
```