# How to select data only with a unique email field?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to select data from a table. The data has an Email field which is not unique. Now i only want to select the first item with an Email of its kind and ignore the others.

I tried:

```
var users = _context.Appointments.Where(p => (p.userId == userId))
            .Select(p => new MyUserModel
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Email = p.User.Email
            });

return users.ToList();
```

I wanted to use `Distinct()`, but my elements are not unique, they have a different `id`.

How could I go about doing that?

Comment: Have you tried GroupBy with Count? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count

Comment: Just to clarify for myself - do you need to select the first record with definite email only? If yes, consider to group them by email and select the first element from every group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if this field is repeated, then I do not need to select this
>   element

You can group by the email and then perform a filter to retain the objects that don't repeat by email and then follow it with your current logic. Example:

```
var users = _context.Appointments
                .Where(p => p.userId == userId)
                .GroupBy(p => p.User.Email) 
                .Where(g => g.Count() == 1) // if there is only one object with this email, then retain it otherwise discard it
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .Select(p => new MyUserModel
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    ...
                    Email = p.User.Email
                    ...
                });

return users.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, but after that I have the exception `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`. Before that, I could get all the meanings. Maybe something else is needed?

Comment: @senjust mhmm, try again with the edited code and let me know where the exception occurs.

Comment: I used the edited code. the exception I have in the line `return users.ToList();` is now users is empty...

Comment: I use IEnumerable, maybe the problem is this?

Comment: @senjust the `users` list will only be _empty_ if `_context.Appointments` returned no records or if every object from the source had a duplicate email elsewhere in the source which would then mean the `Where` clause in the pipeline above filters it out. I don't see any reason why the code I've suggested is returning an empty list apart from the aforementioned reasons, what I recommend is to debug your program and see what's going on.