# SQL to LINQ expres

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I'm trying to convert a SQL expression to Linq but I can't make it work, does anyone help?

```
SELECT 
COUNT(descricaoFamiliaNovo) as quantidades
FROM VeiculoComSeminovo
group by descricaoFamiliaNovo
```

I try this:

```
ViewBag.familiasCount = db.VeiculoComSeminovo.GroupBy(a => a.descricaoFamiliaNovo).Count();
```

I need to know how many times each value repeats, but this way it shows me how many distinct values ​​there are in the column.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/ or English please

Comment: google translated

Comment: Translating: I am trying to convert a SQL expression to Linq but I can't make it work, does anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far. Can you show what LINQ you have written.

Comment: db.VeiculoComSeminovo.GroupBy(a => a.descricaoFamiliaNovo).Count(); 


This way the program is as long as the "descriptionFamiliaNovo" appears and it is not this information I need

Comment: Please add this into your question rather than as a comment. What output does this produce and what are you expecting?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [LINQ with groupby and count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7285714/861716).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var list = from a in db.VeiculoComSeminovo
                       group a by a.descricaoFamiliaNovo into g
                       select new ViewBag{
                                  familiasCount=g.Count()
                       };
```

or

```
var list = db.VeiculoComSeminovo.GroupBy(a => a.descricaoFamiliaNovo)
                                .Select (g => new ViewBag
                                     {
                                      familiasCount=g.Count()
                                     });
```

If you need column value:

```
new ViewBag{
   FieldName=g.Key,
   familiasCount=g.Count()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `GROUP BY` unless there are fields other than the one in `COUNT`. Try

```
SELECT 
COUNT(descricaoFamiliaNovo) as quantidades
FROM VeiculoComSeminovo
```

UPDATE, from your comment:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(descricaoFamiliaNovo) as quantidades,
descricaoFamiliaNovo
FROM VeiculoComSeminovo
GROUP BY descricaoFamiliaNovo
```

That's it as SQL. In LINQ it is something like:

```
var reponse = db.VeiculoComSeminovo.GroupBy(a => a.descricaoFamiliaNovo)
                                   .Select ( n => new 
                                     {Name = n.key,
                                      Count = n.Count()
                                     }
                                     )
```

Not tested.

Comment: Peter, I need to know how many incidents there are in each index of the "descricaoFamiliaNovo" column. Example: ONIX = 1 times, PRISMA = 20 times...
And that was the only way I could think without having to make countless querrys

Answer (score 0):

Ty all for the help.

I solved the problem using this lines:

```
// get the objects on db
var list = db.VeiculoComSeminovo.ToList();
// lists to recive data    
List<int> totaisFamilia = new List<int>();
List<int> totaisFamiliaComSN = new List<int>();
// loop to cycle through objects and add the values ​​I need to their lists
foreach (var item in ViewBag.familias)
{
totaisFamilia.Add(list.Count(a => a.descricaoFamiliaNovo == item && a.valorSeminovo == null));
totaisFamiliaComSN.Add(list.Count(a => a.descricaoFamiliaNovo == item && a.valorSeminovo != null));
}
```

The query was a little slow than I expected, but I got the data