# Filtering Country information from Geographic data by Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have such a table in my database:

```
Id       City       Country
==============================
1          A           X
2          B           X
3          C           X
4          D           X
5          M           Y
6          N           Y
7          O           Y
8          P           Y
9          U           Z
10         V           Z
```

I want to get Countries with first (minimum) Id from the table. The result set should be like:

```
Id       Country
=================
1           X
5           Y
9           Z
```

I can get this result with SQL as :

```
SELECT
    MIN(Id) AS Id,
    Country
FROM
    AllCityList
GROUP BY
    Country
ORDER BY
    Country ASC
```

But when I add this view to EntityFramework since `MIN()` hides PrimaryKey column (Id) I get an error. Hence, I want to convert this query to Linq. How can I write this query in Linq?

Comment: See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count) question...

Comment: Linq syntax should look look like `records.GroupBy(x => x.Country).Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Id).First())`

Comment: @Innat3 I think Order by does not requires in this case. 
`records.GroupBy(x => x.Country).Select(g => g.First())` will work too.

Comment: @SushantYelpale not in this case indeed, but better make sure than be sorry

Comment: @PeterSchneider nfortunately I can not test this query. It falls to Timeout exception even after extending the duration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` with `Min`. The below query groups the data based on *Country* and selects the `Min` *Id*.

```
return AllCityList.GroupBy(d => d.Country).Select(d => 
                    {
                        var first = d.First();
                        return new { Id = d.Min(x => x.Id),  Country = first.Country};
                    });
```

Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/51bwV0) dotnetfiddle which demos the scenario.

Also, with using of `Min` it will make sure to fetch the minimum *Id* in case the column in not a clustered index.

Comment: giving the wrong result. resulting 1st city on the way.

Comment: @SushantYelpale -can you please check the dotnet fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/51bwV0 output to validate the result?

Comment: for your fiddle result should be 3 C X likewise

Comment: The user wants this --- *I want to get Countries with first (minimum) Id from the table*.

Comment: you just modified the fiddle

Comment: created dontetfiddle was created only for *demo* of using `GroupBy` with `Min`

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to work. Unfortunately I have to look for another solution because it takes forever to run this query over 10M records.