# Linq group by with return count

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Net core and Linq. I have table like below

Orders Table

```
OrderId   Status
1         New
2         New
3         In Progress
4         In Progress
5         Closed
6         Closed
```

I have below model

```
public class SummaryEntity
 { 
  public int New { get; set; }
  public int InProgress { get; set; }
  public int Closed { get; set; }
 }
```

Then I need to return and bind to below model like below

```
New : 2
InProgress : 2
Closed : 2
```

I have tried something like below

```
SummaryEntity result = (from item in Orders
                          group item by new { item.Status } into g
                          select new SummaryEntity{ //not sure how to get count and assign it to model }
                           );
```

I am finding hard to group by and assign values to model. Can someone help me to write query. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `SummaryEntity` is single class, how do you want to convert it to list? It seems, that calculating count 3 times will be better

Comment: Hi Sorry my mistek, Removed toList()

Comment: `Orders.Count(o => o.Status == "New")` and the same for other statuses. Also, why count is `string`?

Comment: Hi Pavel which count? I am not able to find it

Comment: yeah pavel i changed to int you are correct

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a web framework, not an ORM. What ORM are you using? EF Core? Something else? Or is `Orders` a list or array?

Comment: Hi Kanavos. Orders is list  and I am using efcore

Comment: If it's a List, you aren't using EF Core any more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ with groupby and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already grouped the items by status, so `g.Key` will contain the status value and `g` itself is an enumerable of the grouped items. If you want to calculate their count use `Count()`, eg :

```
var counts = from item in Orders
             group item by new { item.Status } into g
             select new {status=g.Key, count=g.Count()};
```

This will return one object per status value with its count. Getting different columns for each status is essentially pivoting, converting the rows to columns.

In this case though, where you know the status names in advance, you can convert the results into a dictionary and retrieve the counts by name, eg :

```
var dict=counts.ToDictionary(x=>x.status,x=>x.count);

var model= new SummaryEntity 
           {
               New        = dict.TryGetValue("New",out var c_n)
                            ? c_n : 0,
               InProgress = dict.TryGetValue("InProgress",out var c_p)
                            ? c_p : 0,
               Closed     = dict.TryGetValue("Closed",out var c_c)
                            ? c_c : 0,
           };
```

`Dictionary.TryGetValue` is used to avoid exceptions if a status value is missing

Comment: Very good. You could simplify this using `ToLookup` as in `var byStatus = Orders.ToLookup(o => o.Status);` then you can write `new SummaryEntity { New = byStatus["New"].Count(), ... }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad this doesn't simplify the query, it delays the count calculation. If the OP was using EF, the `GroupBy` would return just the status values and counts, while `ToLookup` would return all items and leave the count calculation to `.Count()`

Comment: I meant simplify the code because you don't need to check for the key. You could always `Orders.ToLookup(o => o.Status, o => o.OrderId);`

Answer (score -1):

You model makes no sense.  You have only status not New, InProgress, Closed.  Try following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("OrderId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            
            dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 1, "New"});
            dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 2, "New"});
            dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 3, "In Progress"});
            dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 4, "In Progress"});
            dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 5, "Closed"});
            dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 6, "Closed"});

            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Status"))
                .Select(x => new { status = x.Key, count = x.Count() })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer but i need to assign it to model, for example if status New is zero then I want to return New : 0

Comment: Your model is strings not integers.  And you need then to create a table in the database that is linked to your model