# Translate an postgresql query to entityframework core in asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to translate the following Postgresql query in a dotnet api application using entityframework core in a way to return a list of objects containing the results in the output of that query.

sql query to translate:

```
select speciality_type, speciality_priority , 
   count(speciality_type)
from specialties
group by speciality_priority, speciality_type
```

desired output:

[image]

knowing that the last column is the count column witch is not initially in the table and that I created in the query.
I want to get all these columns from `_DataAccessObject.SpecialitiesTable` and create from its values another list of an object that I create `object(string type , int priority , int count)`

I tried a lot of stuff like `_DataAccess.SpecialitiesTable.GroupBy(...).Select(...)` most of them give me a error once function is called saying that the EF core statement could not be translated to sql.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Very simple LINQ query. What you have tried so far?

Comment: I was trying stuff like this : _DataAccess.SpecialitiesTable.Select(...).GroupBy(...)

Comment: Show this query in question. It is really easy to search SO and find [GroupBy and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var result = await _DataAccess.SpecialitiesTable
   .GroupBy(s => new { s.speciality_type, s.speciality_priority })
   .Select(g => new 
   {
      g.Key.speciality_type,
      g.Key.speciality_priority,
      count = g.Count()
   })
   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: worked like a charm. basically i get confused on how to set the lambda experssions