# Unable to perform basic JOIN using LINQ Query syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I want to join another table using the query syntax. I am getting the following error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .GroupJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: a => (int?)a.ID,
> innerKeySelector: b => b.aID,
> resultSelector: (a, b) => new {
> // my properties here
> })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

My code looks along the lines of:

```
var q =
    from a in As
    join b in Bs on a.ID equals b.aID into bs
    select new
    {
        // my properties here
    };
```

I want to join the Bs and access `bs` to perform `Count()` on it in my list of properpties.

EDIT: Here is an example using LINQPad 7 (default database).
[image]

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count

Comment: Instead of `GroupJoin` did you try only using [`Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-6.0) ?

Comment: I believe the `GroupJoin` is applied internally by EF Core. I posted by query above (using query syntax). That is all the code. I want to basically have a property `TotalBCount = bs.Count()` as my final select.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `GroupJoin` (`join` which ends with `into`) with EF Core, except situation when you need LEFT JOIN. It's translation is strictly limited.

```cs
var q =
    from a in As
    select new
    {
        ...
        TotalBCount = Bs.Count(b => b.aID == a.ID)
    };
```