# Linq pivot indicator values into additional columns and aggregate data

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to aggregate my data futher using Linq. I have a students table that was not designed properly which contains unnecessary duplications. I have fetched the data and I am trying to aggregate it to be readable easily. The existing structure of the data is as the following:

```
| Course | Class  | Sex | Count |
---------------------------------
| Math   | Junior | M   | 20    |
| Math   | Junior | F   | 15    |
| Other  | Other  | M   | 10    |
| Other  | Other  | F   | 15    |
```

I am trying to convert the above to an easier structure

```
| Course | Class  | Male| Female|
---------------------------------
| Math   | Junior | 20  | 15    |
| Other  | Other  | 10  | 15    |
```

I was using a for loop to get distinct courses and fetch records by sex and merge them into a record, but that's not really efficient. Does any one now a way to achieve that with `Linq` query, I thought it could be handled by Linq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in one go in Linq, by Grouping by Course and Class (I've used a `ValueTuple`, but an anonymous Class grouping key is also OK).

The sums are then obtained by filtering and summing up the Males and Females:

```
var results = courseCounts
     .GroupBy(cc => (cc.Course, cc.Class))
     .Select(grp => new 
             {
                 Course = grp.Key.Course,
                 Class = grp.Key.Class,
                 Male = grp.Where(x => x.Sex == "M").Sum(x => x.Count),
                 Female = grp.Where(x => x.Sex == "F").Sum(x => x.Count)
             });
```

(Minor, but from a performance point of view on larger data sets, it's a bit inefficient to repeat the `.Where(x => x.Sex == "x")` twice - we could for instance key the data in a [Grouping + Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6361918) first)

Comment: Hey StuartLC thank you that works perfectly. Can u give me a pointer how i would implement it if i am using DataTables instead of a model as i couldn't have cc.Course? apologies for the additional question.

Comment: you can get directly from DB, If you want/can write a query. @smned

Comment: @smned it should really just be a matter of replacing the strong Property values with `Dictionary` style property lookups, and a cast, e.g. `cc.Course` becomes `cc["Course"].ToString()` and `Sum(x => x.Count)` would be `Sum(x => int.Parse(x["Count"])). But personally, I would rather take the time to parse the `DataTable` into a strongly typed POCO (or even avoid the DataTable, e.g. load the data with a [`Dapper`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) style strongly typed query.